# Function doesn't have the same behavior if called from a function

Tags: awk

I have written a small function that converts a hex number to decimal using `bc`. When called directly, it works, however when called multiple times from a single statement in another function, it fails.

Here's a demo script to reproduce the issue:

```
awk 'function hd(h) {
  cmd=sprintf("echo \"ibase=16; obase=A; %s\"|bc", h);
  cmd|getline d;
  printf("hd(%s)=%s\n", h, d);
  return d;
}
function test() {
  printf("A=%d, FF=%d\n", hd("A"), hd("FF"));
}
BEGIN {
  printf("A=%d, FF=%d\n", hd("A"), hd("FF"));
  test();
}'
```

Here is the output of this:

```
hd(A)=10
hd(FF)=255
A=10, FF=255
hd(A)=255
hd(FF)=255
A=255, FF=255
```

As you can see, when executed directly in `BEGIN`, it works; however when executed through the `test()` function it fails.

I am using GNU Awk 3.1.5. I also tried GNU Awk 4.1.1 on another machine, it fails in a similar fashion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, you didn't close the pipe after `cmd|getline d`.

adding

```
close(cmd)
```

after the `getline` should fix your problem. `getline` should be used with caution.

P.S.   `printf` in awk is a statement, not a function.

Comment: Wow, nice. I didn't understand your P.S. though.

Comment: @BenoitDuffez `printf "%d", 5` vs `printf("%d",5)`

Comment: Oh, I see. I just find it clearer, but I guess it's more strict to omit the parenthesis. Thanks for this remark.